# Is every proper subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

I know that $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is not necessarily cyclic. But is it true that all of its proper subgroups are cyclic? If not, for which $n$ is it true?

Comment: Of course not. E.g., $(\mathbb{Z}/16\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is isomorphic to $C_{4}\times C_2$, which has a proper subgroup isomorphic to $C_2\times C_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  But it would be true if you take an $n$ for which $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times$ is cyclic.  That would be, it turns out, any $n=1,2,4,p^k$ or $2p^k$ for $p$ an odd prime.

Those are the only $n$ that work,  with the exception, that is, of $n=8$, as @ArturoMagidin points out. Because if a finite abelian group is not cyclic, or of order $p^2$, it contains a proper subgroup of the form $\Bbb Z_p\times\Bbb Z_p$ for some $p$.

Comment: $(\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z})^{\times}\cong C_2\times C_2$, and every *proper* subgroup of this is cyclic. You need to exclude the possibility that $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}\cong C_p\times C_p$, but luckily the only one you are missing is $n=8$, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Right.  So we need to investigate when $\varphi(n)=p^2$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Since $\varphi(n)$ is even, only the case $p=2,n=8$ is possible.